# Looking for an explanation of grounding in relation to computers and DVI-HDMI adapters

Tags: raspberry-pi, grounding, computers, video, hdmi

I recently found that a DVI-HDMI adapter, purchased to connect the micro-HDMI port on my new Raspberry Pi 400 to the DVI port on my monitor, behaves strangely: it works well when connecting to my ATX Linux box, but results in "No Signal" when used with the Pi 400. Adding to the strangeness, the adapter works on an old Pi 3B, but only when using Raspbian Jessie, not the latest Bullseye, and then only at low resolutions, and with a "blinking" problem, the signal going off and on.

Thoroughly mystified, I started to search the net for info on faulty adapters, and found the following QA in the Raspberry Pi forum on SE:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/no-monitor-input-using-a-hdmi-to-dvi-adapter

One of the answers says:

> In my case I noticed that the metal housing of the DVI adapter did not come into contact with the ground of the HDMI, (apparently this problem occurs because raspberry pi does not have a grounding pin), I decided to force a contact between the two ends of the adapter housing.

I would be grateful if people who understand these matters would explain a few things:

- What in the context of a computer is a "grounding pin"? Why is it needed and how can a computer do without one?
- Why would the "metal housing of the DVI adapter" need to come into contact with the ground of the HDMI? The adapter housing is plastic, you can see that in the picture that goes with the answer linked above.
- Is it a good idea to "force a contact between the two ends of the adapter housing"? What could go wrong?

Comment: Did you try other HDMI and/or DVI cables if they work better? Is the monitor earthed/grounded via mains plug, is it a 3-prong plug? Is the Raspberry Pi earthed/grounded via some route or does it just have 2-prong power supply?

Comment: @Justme Thanks, but I'm looking for an explanation, not to troubleshoot my specific adapter/setup. I'm in Europe, all plugs are 2 prong. I don't know the answer to the rest of your questions. I will try another adapter, but I would still appreciate answers to my questions. That's why I'm posting here, rather than in RPi forum. I would like to hear from people who understand electricity and the issues involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely issue is the use of one or more sub-standard items.

The HDMI to DVI adapter does not connect the metal shell of HDMI and DVI connectors together, so the shields of HDMI and DVI cable that should be connected together are not.

Also both the DVI and HDMI cables have more than one ground pin, for example each high speed differential pair has a shield which is supposed to be grounded. At least some sub-standard HDMI cables do not connect all of these and rely only on few or the single low speed DC/data ground pin or the connector shell shield to conduct.

So, as with any other device, any signal or power wire needs a return wire which is called the ground. Your cables and adapters may disconnect some or in worst case all of these return paths, or just leave one return path that can't handle high speeds required, or has too much current flowing in it so that the ground potentials differ or have noise which makes it harder to receive the signals properly.

If the DVI-HDMI adapter does not connect connector shells together, connecting them together will at least make the situation better. The fact that adapter has a plastic case is irrelevant, it's about the electrical connection between connectors.

The Raspberry Pi is usually powered from two-prong USB power supply, so it is not grounded, i.e. connected to earth potential, the output voltage floats, so it may float to some potential that is higher than earth potential. It means that when it is connected to some other equipment, like a grounded/earthed monitor, the accumulated charge gets discharged when connector shells touch so the two devices are at same potential. If the grounds do not connect first, then the charges balance via data pins which might damage the devices. It is even more dangerous if you have a monitor which requires to be connected to earthed mains socket and you have it on non-earthed socket.

Comment: Thank you! As it happens, the monitor is powered by an old 3 prong British computer cable, in a British 3 prong socket on a power strip, which is then via an adapter plugged into a 2 prong socket on a Euro power strip. I guess one prong of the Euro plug/socket is ground, otherwise how could anything work. That also begs my first question - how can the RPi work if not grounded? I'm using the official 5V/3A RPi power supply, connected to the USB-C port on the Pi. I think you've answered my last two questions, but if you could also address the first regarding the Pi, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Regarding connecting the shells of the two connectors of the DVI-HDMI adapter, I take it from your answer that nothing untoward may happen, in fact it may be helpful. I do not run the risk of short-circuiting anything?

Comment: Europlugs are 2-prong. You should not be plugging equipment that need to be connected to earthed(grounded) socket into a non-earthed(non-grounded) socket. That is a hazard for people and the equipment connected together, especially when hot-plugging the equipment while it is connected to mains. No, one plug of eurosocket is not earth/ground, the two prongs are live and neutral. No, RPi does not need ground/earth to work, you can feed it 5V from a power bank and it will happily work isolated from any mains or ground or earth reference.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, does it not follow that all power adapters converting from a 3 prong system (British) to a 2 prong system (Euro) are inviting danger by not grounding equipment that is supposed to be grounded? I'm quite confused at the moment though: what does 'neutral' of the Euro plug do if it does not equate 'ground'? My ignorance is showing, and perhaps this should be its own Q&A, but if you could enlighten me I would appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need the earth prong for equipment to work. Current is carried with live wire and returned in neutral wire. No current flows in earth, and it is bonded with neutral somewhere in the electrical system, so neutral and earth are at same potential. However 3-pronged equipment need earth due to how their mains inlet filter is constructed, and earth is required for safety (your computer metal case is earthed so if a live wire touches it then it blows a fuse and the metal case is not hazardous, disconnecting earth and in faults it is hazardous)

Comment: Thank you, I have learned quite a lot. Answer (together with comments) accepted. I have now got another adapter and it works with the Pi 400, Buster and Bullseye, and with Pi 3B, Jessie but not Bullseye. That will do, problem basically solved.